# Check database table if row exists, then create it if not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to check the database if data for a specific date exists.  If it does not exist, then a new row needs to be inserted into the database for that date.  Here's my code so far in php/sql (after db login info), but I can't get it to work:

```
// gets two data points from form submission
$tablename = $_GET['tablename'];
$date = $_GET['date'];

//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE date = $date) BEGIN Insert into $tablename (date, var1, var2) VALUES ('$date', '', ''); END"
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Please HELP...

Comment: So `date` is supposed to be unique? Any reason not to put a unique key on it and use `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: are the quotes needed at `VALUES ('$date',...`?

Comment: So, there's a form submitted that allows the user to select a date and the table.  Those would need to be able to change based on the user's request.  So date and tablename need to be dynamic.  INSERT IGNORE is not something I'm familiar with.  I am somewhat knew to SQL.

Comment: When a new row is created, I need the remaining inputs to be blank.  Would it be better to use null and leave the quotes off?

Answer (score 1):

Just USE INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE